# any building tool can automatically understand file dependencies in C++ project?

Tags: c++

I have a project with 50+ `.h` files and 50+ `.cpp` files. I'm using `make` to build a project, which looks something like this (it's just a piece of an entire file):

```
HEADERS := $(shell find $(INCLUDE) -name "*.h")
%.obj: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -fPIC -o $@ -g -c $<
```

When I'm making changes to one `.h` file, the whole project has to be re-compiled. It's annoying and time-consuming. But I don't want to hard-code file dependencies inside `Makefile`, since it's even more time-consuming. I would like to have some `make`-like tool, which will find dependencies right inside my `.cpp`/`.h` files, automatically. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
depend:
    g++ -M *.cpp >.depends

-include .depends
```

Better way:

```
SRC=foo.cpp bar.cpp ...
OBJ=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC))
DEPS=$(patsubst %.o,.deps/%.o.dep,$(OBJ))

all: .deps

.deps: 
     mkdir -p .deps

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MD -MF .deps/$@.dep -c -o $@ $<

-include $(DEPS)
```

So compiler will generate all dependencies for each file during build automatically.

Or even better: use Autotools, CMake or other build system that does this job for you.

Answer (score 5):

There are many options, but nothing that works exactly like `make`. Many build systems will generate the Makefiles with dependencies for you though. [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) and [Automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/) are two commonly used systems that work like that. You define your project file in a meta-language and it will generate the Makefiles.

Answer (score 3):

Scons is good in finding the right sources that need to be recompiled.
It scans the files and the headers and builds up an internal dependency tree.
[www.scons.org](http://www.scons.org)

Comment: Moving from make to scons was a very nice experience. Having a configuration file written in python gives a lot of flexibility (it was always difficult for me to modifiy my obscure Makefile), and I'm much more confident in the dependencies management (furthermore, scons knows what to do when the configuration file itself is modified).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gcc then you can use the -M option. It is designed to do exactly what you want i.e. generate a Makefile rule describing the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

[Jam](http://www.perforce.com/jam/jam.html).

[Boost.Build](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/index.html).

The latter is based on a (massively) enhanced version of the former.